# I have some Errors with HTML.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't fix this 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'MaNhaSanXuat'.'

Viewer

```
@Html.DropDownList("MaNhaSanXuat", null, new { @style = "float:left; width: 300px; background:black;height:30px;" })
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.MaNhaSanXuat = new SelectList(NhaSanXuatBUS.DanhSach(), "MaNhaSanXuat","TenNhaSanXuat");
            return View();
        }
```

This is my NhaSanXuatBUS:

```
 public static IEnumerable<NhaSanXuat> DanhSach()
    {
        var db = new ShopOnlineConnectionDB();
        return db.Query<NhaSanXuat>("select * from NhaSanXuat where TinhTrang = 0");
    }
```

I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: how do u define NhaSanXuatBUS.DanhSach()?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the `SelectList` object by using the `ViewBag` see example below:

```cs
@Html.DropDownList("MaNhaSanXuat",(SelectList)ViewBag.MaNhaSanXuat, null, new { @style = "float:left; width: 300px; background:black;height:30px;" })
```

As you can see it's necessary to cast the `ViewBag.MaNhaSanXuat` parameter   to the `SelectList` explicitly. And the third parameter is an optional label. Set this parameter to the `null` when not used.